# What is a good use for an old 35mm slide projector?

Tags: diy, slides, project

I have a Braun Novamat 35mm slide projector which is now completely redundant since I have scanned my entire 35mm slide collection.

I was going to junk it when I started wondering if there was some useful DIY project that I could use it for.

It seems a pity to waste a good lens and condenser. Can you suggest a good use for this in a DIY project?

Comment: You can send it to me, mine is ancient and has no remote

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- You can always use it as a source of
  light for your photography!
- Project slides onto other objects
  to create interesting
  double-exposures.
- Hand paint/draw with markers on slides and project that for interesting, organic images.

But as far as coverting it to do something cool... No clue.

Comment: I found it makes a very good spotlight in my photography, so that is how I am going to use it. Thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 6):

Entertain the cats. Be sure to project slides relevant to their interests.

[image: Cat interacting with projected slide of hummingbird]

(Then, of course, you can do as Jędrek Kostecki suggested, and use the projected slide as the starting point for a new photograph.)

Answer (score 3):

Funny; I just posted this on a comment to [another question](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/11262/is-there-an-easy-way-to-force-chromatic-aberration):

[The Fisheye Tin Lens](http://blog.cow.mooh.org/2010/04/fisheye-tin-cam.html)

This is a lo-fi fisheye lens constructed from a 35mm slide projector lens, a door peephole lens, a soda can, a t-mount adapter, and miscellaneous other junk.

Comment: i quite like that actually, very lomo :-)

Answer (score 1):

I still like projecting slides better than showing images on a computer screen or television myself (even if the latter is more convenient).

You might with a lot of electronics be able to turn it into a projection device for your laptop. Not sure how much it would take, but it wouldn't be trivial.

Answer (score 0):

Some projectors can be modified to be used for digitizing 35mm slides.

Here's an example (in German, but I'm sure there's others around in English, too): http://www.dslr-forum.de/showthread.php?t=305572