# What is this red/blue effect called?

Tags: chromatic-aberration, 3d

I was wondering what's the name of the effect in this photograph. I've heard of Chromatic Aberration, but I'm not really sure.

In any case, is it possible to reproduce this kind of effect (without photoshop, of course)?

[image: Luciano Supervielle]

PS_ The photo is from Luciano Supervielle's latest album.

Comment: Colin K is correct, this is an anaglyph (red/blue 3D) effect. But if you did want to create real chromatic aberration, see: http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/11262/is-there-an-easy-way-to-force-chromatic-aberration

Answer (score 15, accepted):

That is definitely not chromatic aberration. It looks like an artistic effect inspired by [Anaglyph images](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anaglyph_image), which are those old style 3D images that used red and blue goggles.

Edit: On further inspection it appears to actually be an anaglyph image, although it is of course possible that this was used as an artistic effect.

Comment: Right! I forgot to mention it looked like 3D on some spots, like on the glass. Definitely something to check out.
Thanks!

Comment: I put on some 3D glasses (don't know why we had those at work) and it gives a really cool effect! The background, the guy and the glass seem to be on 3 different planes. Try it out.

Comment: The glass appears to be floating :)